# Providing contents of __init__ file in embedded Jython application

Tags: java, python, jython

Background:

I've written a Java application that lets you write and run Python scripts that interact with my application.  I am using Jython to call and run the Python scripts.  A package in my application, `com.user.app.api` contains a handful of classes that are meant to be called from the Python scripts.

Here is the java code that calls my Python Script,

```
package com.user.app;

import org.python.util.PythonInterpreter;

public class MainClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PythonInterpreter p = new PythonInterpreter(null);

        p.execfile("script.py");
    }   
}
```

And here is the contents of script.py,

```
def printAttributes(obj):
    for attribute in obj.__dict__:
        print "\t" + str(attribute)

def function():
    print "Eggs"

import com.user.app.api.Util as u

u.compute()

print "Attributes of class com.user.app.api.Util.java"
printAttributes(u)

import com.user.app.api as a

print "Attributes of package com.user.app.api"
printAttributes(a)

a.__dict__['func'] = function

print "Attributes of package com.user.app.api"
printAttributes(a)

a.func();
```

Here is the contents of Util,

```
package com.user.app.api;

public class Util {
    public static void compute() {
        System.out.println("Computing...");
    }

    // More methods here...
}
```

And running it will output the following,

```
Computing...
Attributes of class com.user.app.api.Util.java
    compute
    __init__
Attributes of package com.user.app.api
    Util
    __name__
Attributes of com.user.app.api
    Util
    func
    __name__
Eggs
```

So from the print statement we can see the Python script is calling a function, the `compute` function, from a Java class, `Util`.
Next the script prints out the attributes of the class `Util`.  We see the `compute` function and the constructor.  Then the script prints out the attributes of the package, and we see the class, `Util`, and the `__name__` attribute.  Now the script will add a function to the `__dict__` attribute of the java package, and we print out the members of the `__dict__` attribute again, confirming that it was added.
Lastly we call the function, and see it's trace statement.

From this we can conclude that a java package can have attributes, including functions.  My question is how can I define these function from within my Java code before calling the script?

**Solved!**

A reference to the java package can be obtained with

```
    PyJavaPackage pack = (PyJavaPackage) PySystemState.packageManager.lookupName("com.user.app.api");
```

Then you can add attributes to the package with

```
pack.__dict__.__setitem__("utility", PyJavaType.fromClass(Util.class));
```

Comment: Methods in Java are always bound to objects or classes. You cannot write methods within packages directly. And your `compute()`-method does not compile as-is.

Comment: You lose me at the very end.  What are you trying to do and what have you tried?

Comment: @DavidCharles I added some code

Comment: @Turing85 Sorry about the mistake.  I edited the question and I hope it's clearer

Comment: So, you really are trying *to* add something to your Java package *by* changing Java code *so* you can use that addition in your Python code?  The way you do that in Java is by defining a new class in the package by creating a new .java source file.  That is how Java works.